# Add logs when call /health

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I developped an application spring-boot I used actuator to provide health indicator. The problem is that I have to develop a custom health and when I call /health I need to log the return of that endpoint.

I created an endpoint /health-bis which call /health and log it's response. But the problem is when a service is unvailable /health return http code 503

Would you have any ideas ?

best regards

Comment: Any code that you tried?! Could you share the full exception?!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task and resolved it by overriding original org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint. I've just simply created my customized one:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "health")
public class CustomHealthEndpoint extends HealthEndpoint {

    public CustomHealthEndpoint(HealthAggregator healthAggregator,
                                HealthIndicatorRegistry registry) {
        super(new CompositeHealthIndicator(healthAggregator, registry));
    }

    @Override
    @ReadOperation
    public Health health() {
        Health health = super.health();
        log.debug("Health status details: {}", health);
        return health;
    }
}
```

And now in my logs every time when I make a call to /health I can see a full status log message.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Filter and register it.

RequestDumperFilter will log requests/responses to the filtered endpoints. It's very verbose so maybe you gonna want to create your own Filter, but that's a good start.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean requestDumperFilter()
{
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    Filter requestDumperFilter = new RequestDumperFilter();
    registration.setFilter(requestDumperFilter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jfneis I tried your solution but the problem is that the filter called on starrtup. When I call /health nothing happen

Comment: @Victor strange, in my application every call to every endpoint is logged (body, headers, etc.). Did you declared this bean inside your configuration class?

Comment: Yes I declared as a bean like your example

Comment: @Victor can you please update your question with what are you getting on the logs so far? I'll compare with my output here.